# snowflake unsupported subquery cannot be evaluated

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

/*Table TEMP has customer hash, effective start date and effective end date. Table CDTLS has    customer hash, effective start date.I want to customer hash, effective from, Customer name from TEMP and CDTLS. I am calculating CDTLS end date on the fly and comparing it with TEMP.EFFECTIVE_FROM and TEMP_EFFECTIVE_TO dates. I get an error that unsupported subquery cannot be evaluated.*/

```
SELECT
        TEMP.CUSTOMER_HASH, 
        TEMP.EFFECTIVE_FROM,
        TEMP.EFFECTIVE_TO,
        CDTLS.NAME
    FROM TEMP
    LEFT CDTLS 
    ON 
    TEMP.CUSTOMER_HASH = CDTLS.CUSTOMER_HASH
    AND 
    CDTLS.EFFECTIVE_FROM <= TEMP.EFFECTIVE_FROM
    AND 
     (
     SELECT VW.EFFECTIVE_TO FROM  
     
        (
         SELECT CUSTOMER_HASH, EFFECTIVE_FROM, LEAD(EFFECTIVE_FROM, 1, '9999-12-31') OVER (PARTITION 
              BY CUSTOMER_HASH ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_FROM ASC) AS EFFECTIVE_TO
         FROM CUST_DETAILS
        ) AS VW
     WHERE CDTLS.CUSTOMER_HASH = VW.CUSTOMER_HASH AND CDTLS.EFFECTIVE_FROM = VW.EFFECTIVE_FROM
     ) >= TEMP.EFFECTIVE_TO
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanted to run this query:

```html
SELECT
        TEMP.CUSTOMER_HASH, 
        TEMP.EFFECTIVE_FROM,
        TEMP.EFFECTIVE_TO,
        CDTLS.NAME
    FROM TEMP
    LEFT join  CDTLS 
    ON 
    TEMP.CUSTOMER_HASH = CDTLS.CUSTOMER_HASH
    AND 
    CDTLS.EFFECTIVE_FROM <= TEMP.EFFECTIVE_FROM
    left join         (
         SELECT CUSTOMER_HASH, EFFECTIVE_FROM, LEAD(EFFECTIVE_FROM, 1, '9999-12-31') OVER (PARTITION 
              BY CUSTOMER_HASH ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_FROM ASC) AS EFFECTIVE_TO
         FROM CUST_DETAILS
        ) AS VW on CDTLS.CUSTOMER_HASH = VW.CUSTOMER_HASH AND CDTLS.EFFECTIVE_FROM = VW.EFFECTIVE_FROM
    where  
   VW.EFFECTIVE_TO >= TEMP.EFFECTIVE_TO
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I am doing. The left join with CDTLS has two conditions effectively. first  TEMP.CUSTOMER_HASH = CDTLS.CUSTOMER_HASH, second to check whether the CDTLS EFFECTIVE_FROM >=TEMP. AND CDTLS.EFFECTIVE_TO >=TEMP.EFFECTIVE_TO. I am calculating the CDTLS.EFFECTIVE_TO DATE in the subquery that gives me one date value that in turn is compared with TEMP.EFFECTIVE_TO. I hope I am able to clarify thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using MIN / MAX / LISTAGG etc in the select query to make it deterministically scalar to check if that helps.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html#differences-between-correlated-and-non-correlated-subqueries